# Azure javaapp logging with log4j to logstash (ELK)

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, logstash, azure-application-insights

I want to send java application logs from log4j to the ELK stack. The app is hosted as a webapp on Azure. Using ELK stack version 5.4.1.

If I understood correctly, there is no trivial way of doing this. I have enabled ApplicationInsights on Azure and configured it to send the metrics including traces (logs) to a blob storage account. On the ELK side, I have configured logstash to use the [logstash-input-azureblob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-diagnostics-tools/tree/master/Logstash/logstash-input-azureblob) plugin.

It seems to be working on the Azure side. At least there are blobs created and populated with data. However, logstash cannot seem to use them. In the logstash logs, I can see loads of messages, for instance like this:

```
[2017-06-15T18:45:16,915][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2017.06.15", :_type=>"%{[@metadata][type]}", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-06-15T18:45:16.781Z %{host} {severityLevel=Verbose, sourceType=Log4j, level=DEBUG, raw=http-outgoing-11129 >> "[0xb7][[0xe9][0xe3][0x8a]k,_[0xb][0xd1]:6[\n]", loggerName=com.microsoft.applicationinsights.core.dependencies.http.wire, threadName=Thread-18, timestamp=2017-06-15T17:21:03+00:00}], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2017.06.15", "_type"=>"%{[@metadata][type]}", "_id"=>"AVytEuooYuUhVejAIgiT", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [message]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:926"}}}}}
```

Any idea on what this is about and, better, how I can get around it?

### Edit

#### `grep -v ^# logstash.yml`

```
node.name: elkdev
path.data: /data/logstash
path.config: /etc/logstash/conf.d
http.host: "10.0.0.0"
path.logs: /var/log/logstash
```

#### `cat conf.d/*` (and some manual editing)

```
input {
  azureblob {
    storage_account_name => "<mystoragename>"
    storage_access_key => "<myaccesskey>"
    container => "logging"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "http://javaendpointdev:80" ]
    path => "/elasticsearch"
    sniffing => false
    manage_template => false
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Logstash is not able to digest the log event. Could you provide some sample log lines and the configuration of Logstash?

Comment: @delixfe, I am not really sure what kind of data is stored on the Azure blob, hence I don't know what is actually sent to logstash. After some trialing and erroring I've been actually storing something in elasticsearch, but the raw messages are there, pretty unusable. Trying to understand how I can have them "unpacked".

Comment: @delixfe, I've updated the post with the logstash configuration.

Comment: @Johan do you must use ES? if you already configured Application Insights, you could simply use its logstash plugin

Comment: @Johan, it looks like the elasticsearch output cannot cope with the azureblob input. 
` "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [message]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:926"`
I would dig into the azureblob documentation. 
You could also write from log4j directly to logstash. Maybe that could be an interim step to unterstand the problem better.